# How to push array inside of an existing array in Mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to generate historical data for a chart.

My app makes a daily request to an API and formats that data to create different points to a chart (snapshots).

But I don't know how to make a mongo array push inside an existing array instead of creating a new document.

This is the document inside my collection:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5a7a24a4e39cd8385477c9f6"
    },
    "chartPoint": [
        [
            {
                "NEO": "109.213",
                "LTC": "145.908",
                "ADA": "0.354973",
                "BCH": "967.817",
                "XRP": "0.763821",
                "ETH": "794.137",
                "BTC": "7809.34",
                "date": "2-6-2018"
            }
        ]
    ],
    "__v": 0
}
```

Chartpoint will be a multi-dimensional array, where each child array is a snapshot with data at different times.

Example:

```
Snapshot1 = [
        {
            "NEO": "109.213",
            "LTC": "145.908",
            "ADA": "0.354973",
            "BCH": "967.817",
            "XRP": "0.763821",
            "ETH": "794.137",
            "BTC": "7809.34",
            "date": "2-6-2018"
        }
    ];

//tomorrows snapshot
Snapshot2 = [
        {
            "NEO": "110.213",
            "LTC": "155.908",
            "ADA": "0.654973",
            "BCH": "927.817",
            "XRP": "0.963821",
            "ETH": "754.137",
            "BTC": "6809.34",
            "date": "3-6-2018"
        }
    ]
```

I want my document to update "chartPoint" with [Snapshot2]. So the document looks like:

```
"chartPoint":[[Snapshot1], [Snapshot2], [Snapshot3], [etc...]]
```

How can I perform this push and update?

Comment: Fetch the doc, append the new snapshot to the existing array, call `save`...

Comment: Try `db.collection.find({_id": ObjectId("5a7a24a4e39cd8385477c9f6")}, {$push:{chartPoint:Snapshot2 }});` in shell